# Azure deployment with github

Tags: azure, deployment

I have a webiste attached to a repository which contains like 5 folders with different projects . I want azure to ignore any push requests I do to 4 of this folders and only do a deployment of the website when I push changes to one specific project ( inside one specific folder ) . I have a .deployment file and it works but azure do a deployment of the specific project each time I submit any change to any of the other projects and I dont want this .

Answer (score 0):

Azure will initiate a deployment whenever a change is published on the branch that you have configured. It has no knowledge of what has changed it simply knows that you have changed something so it redeploys.

You would need to create a specific branch that you could update only when changes to that folder occurred.